# urllib open - how to control the number of retries

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

How can I control the number of retries of `opener.open`?

In the following code, it will send about 6 `GET` HTTP requests (I saw it in the Wireshark sniffer) before the exception gets raised or the code succeeds.

```
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None,url, username, password)
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

try: 
    resp = opener.open(url,None,1)

except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print ("no success")
else:
    print ("success!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`urllib` uses `httplib` for dealing with HTTP connections. If you have a look into `httplib.py` source, and analyze `HTTPConnection` class you will see how `connect` method works.

```
def connect(self):
    """Connect to the host and port specified in __init__."""
    msg = "getaddrinfo returns an empty list"
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(self.host, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
            if self.debuglevel > 0:
                print "connect: (%s, %s)" % (self.host, self.port)
            self.sock.connect(sa)
        except socket.error, msg:
            if self.debuglevel > 0:
                print 'connect fail:', (self.host, self.port)
            if self.sock:
                self.sock.close()
            self.sock = None
            continue
        break

    if not self.sock:
        raise socket.error, msg
```

Actually, the number of tries depends on the length of the list returned by [socket.getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo). The code walks through all available socket options to set the connection up.

I doubt that it makes sense to decrease the number of tries. But you can increase this number like below:

```
maxtries = 3
delay = 3
n = 0
while n < maxtries:
    try: 
        resp = opener.open(url,None,1)
    except e:
        print ("no success")
        n += 1
        sleep(delay)
    else:
        print ("success!")
        break
```